# i am trying to write a code that would tell which direction to go

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm

Challenge: https://www.codewars.com/kata/550f22f4d758534c1100025a/train/python

**My attempt:**

```
array=["NORTH","SOUTH","SOUTH","EAST","WEST","NORTH","WEST"]
list=[]
for i in range(len(array)):

    if array[i]=="NORTH":
        list.append(i)
        for item in array:
            if item == "SOUTH":
                list.append(item)
                array.remove(item)
                break
        array.pop(i)
    elif array[i]=="SOUTH":
        list.append(i)
        for item in array:
            if item == "NORTH":
                list.append(item)
                array.remove(item)
                break

        array.pop(i)
    elif array[i]=="EAST":
        list.append(i)
        for item in array:
            if item == "WEST":
                list.append(item)
                array.remove(item)
                break

        array.pop(i)
    elif array[i]=="WEST":
        list.append(i)
        for item in array:
            if item == "EAST":
                list.append(item)
                array.remove(item)
                break

        array.pop(i)

    else:
        if array[i]!=None:
            print(array)
        else:
            print(list)
```

The problem is that where I try to run in my terminal it is showing this error:

```
line 5, in <module>
    if array[i]=="NORTH":
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It will be great if you help me to figure out this problem and help me to improve my code.

Comment: You are altering the length of `array` while iterating over it - usually a bad idea.

Comment: put in a print that tells you which index you are trying to access, or which item. You'll see you'll try to iterate the list accessing element _n+1_, when it only has _n_ elements.

Comment: so what should i do..please correct me

Answer (score 1):

Rather than appending the result into a new list, update the original list. The index is out of range occurs as your code tries to access index after deleting the values. When we need to update a list, we need to use `enumerate` rather than for loop with list length.

Here is my solution regarding the challenge. This may not the best solution but it passes all test cases:

```
def dirReduc(arr):    
    while True:
        retry = False
        for i, val in enumerate(arr):
            if i+1 < len(arr):
                if val == "NORTH" and arr[i+1] == "SOUTH":
                    del arr[i]
                    del arr[i]
                    retry = True
                    break
                if val == "SOUTH" and arr[i+1] == "NORTH":
                    del arr[i]
                    del arr[i]
                    retry = True
                    break
                if val == "WEST" and arr[i+1] == "EAST":
                    del arr[i]
                    del arr[i]
                    retry = True
                    break
                if val == "EAST" and arr[i+1] == "WEST":
                    del arr[i]
                    del arr[i]
                    retry = True
                    break
        if retry == False:
            break
    return arr
```

**Explanation:**

I have traversed all elements in the array. If I get any consecutive pair which can be annihilate each other, I delete them from the list. Such pairs are: (NORTH, SOUTH), (SOUTH, NORTH), (EAST, WEST), and (WEST, EAST).

I continue this operation until there is no removable pair in the list. Finally, I return the updated list.

**Reference:**

- [enumerate Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: I am glad. Accept the answer and upvote when you're capable.